# The type com.liferay.petra.sql.dsl.query.DSLQuery cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: liferay-7, liferay-service-builder

I am following a beginner's tutorial from [here](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018164091-What-is-Service-Builder-) in order to create a service and then consume it from another module (eg. a Portlet)

Everything goes well until I try to deploy it - there is an error in the generated classes: `The type com.liferay.petra.sql.dsl.query.DSLQuery cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate `build.gradle` file and add the following dependency:

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.petra.sql.dsl.api"
```

Note: you have to add it in both *-api and *-service `build.gradle` files

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using a more generic way that will organize all Liferay related imports for you with just a single line:

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.api", version: "7.3.5-ga6"
```

Answer (score 0):

My workspace was working fine and next day when I started my system I faced problem that workspace is invalid, don't know what happened. I took new liferay workspace and then copy pasted my service builder then on deployment I faced this issue.
The type com.liferay.petra.sql.dsl.query.DSLQuery cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
I tried to add

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.petra.sql.dsl.api"
```

but then facing new issue.
I don't think so this import would help, that is something else problem
Luckily I had my current workspace in zip format last week as a backup now again I m imported that zip and retried to build service again, now it is working fine.
thanks